Trying to convert letter shapes to vectors/x y positions
Once in a while, I have to sign stacks of documents using a mouse, and find it annoying. I've used pyautogui to create a script where I laboriously "built" my signature with crude, basic letter shapes, and that more-or-less works - but what I'd really prefer is to convert some letters in a nice-looking font to an array of X/Y pairs that describe relative positions - e.g.,
# A very crude 'p' :)
[
[ 0, 28 ],   # 28px up
[ 5, -7 ],   # 5px right, 7px down
[ -5, -7 ],   # 5px left, 7px down
]

I've tried writing it in Inkscape using Firas (a font with very thin lines), converting it to a path, and saving as an SVG; unfortunately, this gives me absolute position pairs, like "86.45696533 51.07654447" - and I can't think of a way to make that useful.

Well, since nobody had an answer... I managed to come up with one by fiddling in my spare moments. Here's the process, for anyone who wants to replicate it:

Using a vector image editor (Inkscape, Adobe, etc.), create a viewport that
is just big enough for your signature. I used 100px x 450px for mine.

Create your signature using the thinnest possible font (e.g. Firas Hair Thin); thick strokes will cause your mouse to make multiple passes over the same area. Make SURE you convert the text object to a path - open the resulting SVG file with a text editor and look for the '<path id=' entries.

Go to the SVG-to-XY converter at https://spotify.github.io/coordinator/ and
upload your SVG. Under 'Refine dots', you may need to set a negative Y translation just to see the display - I guess that part doesn't work too well...
I'm grateful they made the tool available, though!
Keep the number of points as low as you can - your draw time depends on it. 200 worked for me - it takes ~12 seconds to write my signature. Set the dot radius to 1. Download the resulting JSON file.

Save the following script on your system; change the 'infile' variable to
point to wherever you saved the JSON file. For extra credit, run it via a
keyboard macro (e.g., with AutoHotkey.) Works great!



    #!/usr/bin/python
    import pyautogui as pg
    
    infile = 'C:\\Users\\BWS\\python\\coordinator.json'
    
    # Read in the data file and assign it to 'coords'
    with open(infile) as fd: exec('coords = ' + fd.read())
    
    # Round all the elements
    coords = [[round(i) for i in j] for j in coords]
    # This is the "zero" coordinate; movement is relative to this point
    lastx, lasty = coords[0]
    
    for x, y in coords:
        # Distance between letters, etc.
        if abs(x - lastx) >= 20 or abs(y - lasty) >= 20:
            pg.move(x - lastx, y - lasty, 0.25)
        else:
            pg.drag(x - lastx, y - lasty, button='left')
    
        lastx = x
        lasty = y

